# How do I proceed with this question of Least Squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

The question is-

> The following data shows atmospheric pollutants $y_{i}$ (relative to an EPA standard) at half hourintervals $t_{i}$
> $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
> t_{i} & 1     & 1.5  & 2    & 2.5  & 3    & 3.5  & 4    & 4.5  & 5 \\ \hline
> y_{i} & -0.15 & 0.24 & 0.68 & 1.04 & 1.21 & 1.15 & 0.86 & 0.41 & -0.08\\ \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

What form of the curve should I assume to solve this equation, quadratic or linear?
The solution given in my college's module assumes the curve as $y=a_{2}t^{2}+a_{1}t+a_{0}$ but won't explain why.

Or could this question be incomplete? It seems to me

Comment: Try plotting the data, what kind of curve seems like a good fit to you?

Comment: Looks like a quadratic curve. Thanks! @NoahSolomon